# Wordpress wp nav menu doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

I don't understand why it's impossible for me to get my custom menu on my front-end page
I use:

```
<?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location' => 'jdsMainMenu',
            'depth'          => '1',
            'menu_class'     => 'jds-main-menu-list',
            'menu_id'        => 'jds-nav',
            'container'      => '',
            'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="jds-main-menu-list">%3$s</ul>'
        ));
 ?>
```

I have my menu in WordPress back office.
I try to make:
`var_dump(get_registered_nav_menus());`

My menu is available: but nothing display with wp_nav_menu...

Maybe some one have an idea...

Comment: I think you either need to set echo argument to true or echo the output returned by wp_nav_menu

Comment: Please go through this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

Comment: How do you register the navigation?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are using correct ID for theme location 
[screenshot](http://prntscr.com/io36sx)

```
function register_my_menus() {  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'jdsMainMenu' => __( 'Navigation Menu' )
         )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );

 wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location' => 'jdsMainMenu',
            'depth'          => '1',
            'menu_class'     => 'jds-main-menu-list',
            'menu_id'        => 'jds-nav',
            'container'      => '',
            'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="jds-main-menu-list">%3$s</ul>'
        ));
```